# BroadcastReceiver for unplug of headphone

Tags: android

Hi i am working on an application that generate an event when ever the headphone is removed from the mobile phone.
I have created a broadcast receiver with receive method as

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.i("Broadcast Receiver", "Hello");
        if( (action.compareTo(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG))  == 0)   //if the action match a headset one
        {
            int headSetState = intent.getIntExtra("state", 0);      //get the headset state property
            int hasMicrophone = intent.getIntExtra("microphone", 0);//get the headset microphone property
            if( (headSetState == 0) && (hasMicrophone == 0))        //headset was unplugged & has no microphone
            {

                    //do whatever
            }
        }           

    }
```

Calling this method as follows

```
 IntentFilter receiverFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
        HeadSetBroadCastReceiver receiver = new HeadSetBroadCastReceiver();
        registerReceiver( receiver, receiverFilter );
```

also i have register this in manifest as

```
   <receiver android:name=".HeadsetBroadCastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and permission

But this doesnot works can anyone guide me through this?

Comment: Common guys no one could guide me?

Comment: [Check this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092438/intent-action-headset-plug-is-received-when-activity-starts)

Comment: [This works](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6366238/726863)

Comment: I have check that out but i nothing is displayed on logcatif (intent.hasExtra("state")){
    if (headsetConnected && intent.getIntExtra("state", 0) == 0){
     headsetConnected = false;
     Log.d("Values","Inside");
     }
    }
    else if (!headsetConnected && intent.getIntExtra("state", 0) == 1){
     headsetConnected = true;
    }
 }

Comment: is your `onReceive()` called?

Comment: HeadstateReceiver class description is not provided can you explain me a bit

Comment: Yes that was my onReceive() call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem here is that this broadcast has flag [Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY) set. This means that manifest receivers will not catch that. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249023/detecting-whether-a-headset-is-plugged-in-or-not/6366238#6366238) is a full explanation.

Answer (score 25):

it's tricky point but you can use BroadCast as the Following working well with me
in your **Activity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myReceiver = new HeadSetReceiver();
}
```

and in **onResume()** Method register your Broadcast

```
public void onResume() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
    super.onResume();
}
```

then Declare your BroadCast in your Activity

```
private class HeadSetReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {
            int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
            switch (state) {
            case 0:
                Log.d(TAG, "Headset unplugged");
                break;
            case 1:
                Log.d(TAG, "Headset plugged");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it's Help ,,,

Answer (score 2):

Answer to my question was this.. Thanks for replying each and everyone

```
class NoisyAudioStreamReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY.equals(intent.getAction())) {
           // pause();
            Log.d("Mesage","Unplug");
            Toast.makeText(context, "Heello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
 IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY);
        NoisyAudioStreamReceiver receiver = new NoisyAudioStreamReceiver();
        registerReceiver( receiver, intentFilter );
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to toggle breakpoint inside onReceive and check in Debug mode what kind of event are you receiving when you plugin your handset device.
And then insert this event instead of Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG
Thanks.

Comment: I think broadcast receiver is not getting register.:(

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is a problem with the registering of broadcast receiver with the respective intent. Refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524923/issues-with-action-headset-plug-broadcast-in-android?rq=1) and see if it works out.

Exception in my logcat

```
07-30 12:41:01.448: E/ActivityThread(321): Activity com.example.test.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.example.test.BroadcastsHandler@44ee81d8 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
07-30 12:41:01.448: E/ActivityThread(321): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.example.test.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.example.test.BroadcastsHandler@44ee81d8 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
07-30 12:41:01.448: E/ActivityThread(321):  at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(ActivityThread.java:939)
07-30 12:41:01.448: E/ActivityThread(321):  at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.getReceiverDispatcher(ActivityThread.java:734)
07-30 12:41:01.448: E/ActivityThread(321):  at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:791)
07-30 12:41:01.448: E/ActivityThread(321):  at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:778)
07-30 12:41:01.448: E/ActivityThread(321):  at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:772)
07-30 12:41:01.448: E/ActivityThread(321):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:318)
07-30 12:41:01.448: E/ActivityThread(321):  at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
07-30 12:41:01.448: E/ActivityThread(321):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-30 12:41:01.448: E/ActivityThread(321):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-30 12:41:01.448: E/ActivityThread(321):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-30 12:41:01.448: E/ActivityThread(321):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-30 12:41:01.448: E/ActivityThread(321):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-30 12:41:01.448: E/ActivityThread(321):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-30 12:41:01.448: E/ActivityThread(321):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-30 12:41:01.448: E/ActivityThread(321):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-30 12:41:01.448: E/ActivityThread(321):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 12:41:01.448: E/ActivityThread(321):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-30 12:41:01.448: E/ActivityThread(321):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-30 12:41:01.448: E/ActivityThread(321):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-30 12:41:01.448: E/ActivityThread(321):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is how I registered a broadcast receiver in one of my projects:

onCreate:

```
$////////////////broadcast reciever/////////////
    IntentFilter iFilter = new IntentFilter();
    iFilter.addAction(handler.ACTION);
    iFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    handler = new HandleTime();
    registerReceiver(handler, iFilter);
```

Manifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```