# Way to ensure delivery of Action HEADSET_PLUG for ZTE T815 Android phone

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, headset

I have registered a BroadcastReceiver to receive ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG which works fine for most devices, ie it is called whenever the headset is plugged or unplugged. But on others eg the ZTE T815, the Intent is never sent/received when the headset is plugged/unplugged.

For reference here is the code for the receiver registration:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver headsetPlugReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Received intent=" + intent);
        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
};

public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onCeate(savedState);
    // ...
    registerReceiver(headsetPlugReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG));
}
```

Further info:
The Intent is dispatched but only after the HEADSET_HOOK command is fired on the headset.

And when the Intent is dispatched

```
final int microphone = intent.getIntExtra("microphone", 0);
```

always returns 0 (ie no microphone).

So

1. Is there some config/code that can force the delivery of this
   Intent?
2. How do I get the Intent to correctly report whether a
   microphone exists or not?

Comment: Are you sure its device dependent or is it microphone dependent?

Comment: Device dependent. Several microphones work fine on several dozen other devices. No microphones work on this device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the ZTE T815 has an OMTP TRRS config for its audio socket instead of CTIA/AHJ like every other modern Android device.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_%28audio%29

A sad state of affairs, especially when trying to use audio feed inpout across products.